# iPhone Objective-C Simplest Way to get a stock quote

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, stock

I'm wondering what is the simplest way to get the current price of a stock from say Yahoo finance (or similar) in Objective-C For the iPhone SDK.

Simple is the key, I am looking for current price, and days movement.

I haven't had much luck finding an iPhone code example or library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `NSURLRequest` object to retrieve the data at this address:

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv

Using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to change the AAPL to the stock ticker you want to use. The retrieved data is in CSV format so you will need to parse that to get the individual values you require. This can be done in this simple case using `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString: @","]` to retieve an array which you can parse using two loops.

Comment: awesome, thats on the right track of what I'm looking for. Have you seen any fuller code I can use?

Comment: I've written some code to do this, but it's really only about 5 lines long. If you look into the Apple documentation for NSURLRequest, NSArray and NSString you should find everything you need :)

Comment: from can we get finance rss feeds?. It seems yahoo finance rss feeds can be used only for non-commercial (not sure if thats gonna help for iphone apps)

Comment: Up: is there an api limit to this request? X number of requests per IP Address perhaps?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I wouldn't be that surprised if there is.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest code snippet for this I know is along the lines of:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BP.L&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"]]);
```

It retrieves BP's share price in London and prints it to the console.

Answer (score 2):

For a full code example of this, check out the [AAPLot sample application](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg/examples/AAPLot) in the [Core Plot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  It downloads stock data and plots it with open-high-low-close information, as well as trading volume.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that example before I asked the question. This is to what lead to me saying 'simple' ;) That example is pretty advanced (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get a lot of your answers from the [Yahoo Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/), in the Finance section.

Comment: the yahoo finance dev site is a joke. All it has is this: http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/
rss feeds...

Comment: What's wrong with using the RSS feeds to get the stock quotes?

Answer (score 1):

The [Quandl Stock API](https://www.quandl.com/help/api-for-stock-data) is free and let's you retrieve Yahoo or Google finance data.  In addition to CSV, it provides the data in some more modern formats like JSON and XML.  Here's how to retrieve for CSV:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.csv
```

Here's the small change to retrieve in JSON format:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.json
```

No API key is needed, but getting an API key is free and allows you to make up to 5000 calls per hour.

Another big plus is that the same API can be used to retrieve fundamental data about companies.

Comment: The only problem with using these API's is that they provide only open, low, high and close values for the day. But they don't provide the current value at a given time.