# Launch Apple's Stocks app, with a particular stock selected

Tags: iphone, url, stocks, custom-url

I would like to launch Apple's Stocks app to show information for a particular stock, on a non-jailbroken phone. I'm not interesting in how to [get a quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265955/iphone-objective-c-simplest-way-to-get-a-stock-quote) or [graph a stock myself](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg/examples/AAPLot), just opening Stocks.app.

I was hoping that the Stocks app would have a custom URL format, so opening a URL like `stocks://AAPL` would do the trick. But I haven't found anything documenting such a  scheme, and suspect it doesn't exist.

Any other ideas, or is it impossible to integrate with the native Stocks app?

Comment: I added a feature enhancement request to Apple for this at rdar://7999314. The more people who request this feature, the more likely it is that it will be implemented. Visit http://bugreport.apple.com to add a feature request, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist, Apple publishes a [list of iPhone URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1) - Mail, phone, text, Maps, YouTube, and iTunes.

Maybe you could just pull the stock info yourself? There must be some kind of web service you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as Apple pulls its stock information from Yahoo! Finance. Maybe you can try opening a UIWebView/Safari and direct to the Yahoo! Finance as the next best thing?

Comment: -1. Where Apple pulls the data from is irrelevant. The key is to finding out if the Stocks app offers a URL that can be called from another app.